# uneven behaviour create a post in using json api with white spaces

Tags: json, plugin-json-api

```
$url = "http://192.168.201.214/wordpress/?json=posts/create_post&dev=1&nonce=".$_POST["nonace"].
        "&title=".$_POST["title"]."&content=".$_POST["content"]."&slug=".$_POST["title"]."&status=draft";
//echo $url; exit;
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
$ar=json_decode($r);
//print_r($ar);
    echo "status ------------------------------ ".$ar->status."<br>";
    echo "Link ------------------------------ ".$ar->post->url."<br>";
```

this my code to create a post everthing is fine but when i create a post with spaces in my title or content it only considering first word and leaving reamining

Examples:content without spaces

in my return json object iam getting it like

```
"status": "draft",
    "title": "sivaji",
    "title_plain": "sivaji",
    "content": "<p>ThisIsVeryGood<\/p>\n",
```

Examples:content with spaces

in my return json object iam getting it like

```
"status": "draft",
    "title": "sivaji",
    "title_plain": "sivaji",
    "content": "<p>This<\/p>\n"
```

Iam usig ajax call and text boxes to post the content

Answer (score 1):

You should be [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)ing your content. Whitespace is not a valid character in URLs. If you have access to WordPress functions on the sending side you can use [`esc_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url). I suspect that has a lot to do with your problem.

Be aware that there is a character limit on `$_GET` strings. If you are going to be posting long content you should be sending over `$_POST`.